# Slow Query with RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE wait info

Tags: sql-server, memory, wait-types, plan-cache

Hi I see lot of `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` as wait_info when i run `sp_whoisactive` in my sql database server.I see few `CXCONSUMER` as well.I learned that `CXCONSUMER` is because of parallel query execution.How to avoid `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE`?

I see slow query execution whenever the user connection increases.Since most of the queries are running in parallel mode and `MAXDOP` is set to 0(causing the queries to utilize all CPU cores.) i believe that this makes other queries to wait.I am not sure whether i am right about this.
Is there any other inference/suggestions?

Here is the results for `EXEC sp_Blitz @OutputType = 'MARKDOWN', @CheckServerInfo = 1;`

> **Priority 1: Backup**:
>
> - Backing Up to Same Drive Where Databases Reside  - 350 backups done on drive D:\ in the last two weeks, where database files also live.
>     This represents a serious risk if that array fails.
>
> **Priority 1: Reliability**:
>
> **Priority 5: Reliability**:
>
> - Priority Boost Enabled  - Priority Boost sounds awesome, but it can actually cause your SQL Server to crash.
>
> **Priority 10: Performance**:
>
> - Query Store Disabled - The new SQL Server 2016 Query Store feature has not been enabled on this database.
>
>   - Services.Demp
>
> **Priority 20: Reliability**:
>
> - Plan Guides Failing Services.Demp - The [Services.Demp] database has plan guides that are no longer valid, so the queries involved may be
>     failing silently.
>
> **Priority 50: DBCC Events**:
>
> - Overall Events  - 368 DBCC events have taken place between Oct 18 2018  5:18AM and Oct 19 2018 10:45AM. This does not include CHECKDB
>     and other usually benign DBCC events.
>
> **Priority 50: Performance**:
>
> - Poison Wait Detected: CMEMTHREAD & NUMA  - 0:12:38:38 of this wait have been recorded. In servers with over 8 cores per NUMA node,
>     when CMEMTHREAD waits are a bottleneck, trace flag 8048 may be needed.
> - Poison Wait Detected: RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE  - 10:10:03:16 of this wait have been recorded. This wait often indicates killer performance
>     problems.
> - Poison Wait Detected: THREADPOOL  - 0:06:59:08 of this wait have been recorded. This wait often indicates killer performance problems.
>
> **Priority 50: Reliability**:
>
> - Page Verification Not Optimal
>
>   - Services.Demp - Database [Services.Demp] has NONE for page verification.  SQL Server may have a harder time recognizing and
>       recovering from storage corruption.  Consider using CHECKSUM instead.
>   - iyeTek.Services.ValueObjects - Database [iyeTek.Services.ValueObjects] has NONE for page verification.  SQL
>       Server may have a harder time recognizing and recovering from storage
>       corruption.  Consider using CHECKSUM instead.
> - Remote DAC Disabled  - Remote access to the Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC) is not enabled. The DAC can make remote
>     troubleshooting much easier when SQL Server is unresponsive.
>
> **Priority 100: Performance**:
>
> - Many Plans for One Query  - 58 plans are present for a single query in the plan cache - meaning we probably have parameterization issues.
> - Memory Pressure Affecting Queries  - 11 forced grants reported in the DMV sys.dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores, indicating memory
>     pressure has affected query runtimes.
> - Repetitive Steps In Maintenance Plans  - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance is doing repetitive work on indexes and statistics.
>     Perhaps it's time to try something more modern?
> - Shrink Database Step In Maintenance Plan
>
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Check Database])
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Cleanup history])
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Cleanup Narrative Locks])
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Full backup])
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Reorganize Index])
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Scrub old backups])
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Shrink Database])
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Transaction backup])
>   - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases is as outdated as maintenance
>       plans. (Schedule: [AICS Maintenance.Update Statistics Task])
>
> **Priority 110: Performance**:
>
> - Active Tables Without Clustered Indexes
>
>   - Services.Demp - The [Services.Demp] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that are being actively queried.
> - Parallelism Rocket Surgery
>
>   - Services.Demp - [Services.Demp] has a make_parallel function, indicating that an advanced developer may be manhandling SQL Server
>       into forcing queries to go parallel.
>
> **Priority 150: Performance**:
>
> - Deadlocks Happening Daily  - 1316 deadlocks have been recorded since startup.
> - Foreign Keys Not Trusted SQLdmRepository - The [SQLdmRepository] database has foreign keys that were probably disabled, data was
>     changed, and then the key was enabled again.  Simply enabling the key
>     is not enough for the optimizer to use this key - we have to alter the
>     table using the WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT parameter.
> - Queries Forcing Join Hints  - 6033 instances of join hinting have been recorded since restart.  This means queries are bossing the SQL
>     Server optimizer around, and if they don't know what they're doing,
>     this can cause more harm than good.  This can also explain why DBA
>     tuning efforts aren't working.
> - Queries Forcing Order Hints  - 8738 instances of order hinting have been recorded since restart.  This means queries are bossing the SQL
>     Server optimizer around, and if they don't know what they're doing,
>     this can cause more harm than good.  This can also explain why DBA
>     tuning efforts aren't working.
>
> **Priority 170: File Configuration**:
>
> - File growth set to percent
>
>   - Services.Demp - The [Services.Demp] database file D:\SQL_Log\Services.Demp.Test.ldf has grown to 6 GB, and is using
>       percent filegrowth settings. This can lead to slow performance during
>       growths if Instant File Initialization is not enabled.
>
> **Priority 200: Informational**:
>
> - Agent Jobs Starting Simultaneously  - Multiple SQL Server Agent jobs are configured to start simultaneously. For detailed schedule
>     listings, see the query in the URL.
> - Linked Server Configured
>
>   - A-SQL-02 is configured as a linked server. Check its security configuration to make sure it isn't connecting with SA or some other
>       bone-headed administrative login, because any user who queries it
>       might get admin-level permissions.
>   - E-SQL-02 is configured as a linked server. Check its security configuration to make sure it isn't connecting with SA or some other
>       bone-headed administrative login, because any user who queries it
>       might get admin-level permissions.
> - Replication In Use Services.Demp - Database [Services.Demp] is a replication publisher, subscriber, or distributor.
>
> **Priority 200: Non-Active Server Config**:
>
> - scan for startup procs  - This sp_configure option isn't running under its set value.  Its set value is 1 and its running value is 0.
>     When someone does a RECONFIGURE or restarts the instance, this setting
>     will start taking effect.
>
> **Priority 200: Non-Default Server Config**:
>
> - Agent XPs  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
> - backup compression default  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
> - cost threshold for parallelism  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 5 and it has been set to 20.
> - Database Mail XPs  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
> - max degree of parallelism  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 8.
> - max server memory (MB)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 2147483647 and it has been set to 102400.
> - max text repl size (B)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 65536 and it has been set to -1.
> - optimize for ad hoc workloads  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
> - priority boost  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
> - remote query timeout (s)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 600 and it has been set to 1800.
>
> **Priority 200: Performance**:
>
> - Shrink Database Step In Maintenance Plan - The maintenance plan AICS Maintenance has a step to shrink databases in it. Shrinking databases
>     is as outdated as maintenance plans.
> - User-Created Statistics In Place
>
>   - Services.Demp - [Services.Demp] has 39 user-created statistics. This indicates that someone is being a rocket scientist with the
>       stats, and might actually be slowing things down, especially during
>       stats updates.
>
> **Priority 210: Non-Default Database Config**:
>
> - ANSI NULL Default Enabled - This database setting is not the default.
>
>   - Services.Demp
>
> **Priority 210: Non-Default Database Scoped Config**:
>
> - QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES - Set value: 1 Default: 0 Set value for secondary: Empty Default value for secondary: Empty
>
>   - Services.Demp
>
> **Priority 240: Wait Stats**:
>
> - 1 - CXCONSUMER  - 44128.7 hours of waits, 914.1 minutes average wait time per hour, 12.5% signal wait, 52996076747 waiting tasks, 3.0 ms
>     average wait time.
> - 2 - CXPACKET  - 36512.8 hours of waits, 756.4 minutes average wait time per hour, 4.7% signal wait, 34981080293 waiting tasks, 3.8 ms
>     average wait time.
>
> **Priority 250: Server Info**:
>
> - Default Trace Contents  - The default trace holds 29 hours of data between Oct 18 2018  5:15AM and Oct 19 2018 10:53AM. The default trace
>     files are located in: D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>     Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log
> - Drive C Space  - 691653.00MB free on C drive
> - Drive D Space  - 3783842.00MB free on D drive
> - Hardware  - Logical processors: 40. Physical memory: 127GB.
> - Hardware - NUMA Config
>
>   - Node: 0 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 10 Offline schedulers: 0 Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 0 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 152
>   - Node: 1 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 10 Offline schedulers: 0 Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 0 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 152
>   - Node: 2 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 10 Offline schedulers: 0 Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 1 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 0
>   - Node: 3 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 10 Offline schedulers: 0 Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 1 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 0
> - Instant File Initialization Enabled  - The service account has the Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks permission.
> - Server Last Restart  - Jun 19 2018  6:34PM
> - Server Name  - E-SQL-01
> - Services
>
>   - Service: SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER) runs under service account NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher. Last startup time:
>       not shown.. Startup type: Manual, currently Running.
>   - Service: SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) runs under service account NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE. Last startup time: Jun 20 2018  6:25PM.
>       Startup type: Automatic, currently Running.
>   - Service: SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) runs under service account NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE. Last startup time: not shown.. Startup
>       type: Automatic, currently Running.
> - SQL Server Last Restart  - Jun 20 2018  6:25PM
> - SQL Server Service  - Version: 13.0.5026.0. Patch Level: SP2. Edition: Standard Edition (64-bit). AlwaysOn Enabled: 0. AlwaysOn Mgr
>     Status: 2
> - Windows Version  - I have no idea which version of Windows you're on. Sorry.
>
> **Priority 254: Rundate**:
>
> - Captain's log: stardate something and something...

Here is the screenshot of `EXEC sp_BlitzCache @SortOrder = 'memory grant';`
[image]

I ran the ring buffer query to check physical memory.Here is the result and also i see that cache is cleared in regular intervals.

[image]

I don't understand why this is tagged as hold or a broad question.
Provided the specific informations.

Here is the plan for a slow query.
[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkQbcn2sQ)

Comment: https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/resource_semaphore/

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a comment answer, because we need a lot more information.

Resource semaphore isn't typically something you troubleshoot by looking at one query plan.

It's the result of a bunch of queries (or sometimes a bunch of the same query) asking for and getting memory, while other queries are waiting for them to finish and release it.

Since you're on a version of SQL Server reporting CXCONSUMER waits, head on over here: http://firstresponderkit.org -- it's the repo for the open source scripts my company writes.

You can grab them all, but to start with you'll need `sp_Blitz`, and `sp_BlitzCache`.

Run this command, and update your question with the results:

`EXEC sp_Blitz @OutputType = 'MARKDOWN', @CheckServerInfo = 1;`

Next, run this:

`EXEC sp_BlitzCache @SortOrder = 'memory grant';`

And [paste the plans](http://pastetheplan.com) for the top couple/few queries so you can update your question to share them.

But fair warning: if you're hitting resource semaphore waits, there's a good chance your plan cache has cleared out plans for the offending queries already.

Comment: I will post the results soon.I am having the exact same issue you mentioned.Bunch of queries are making other queries wait.I have dealt with this issue earlier,that time i fixed the slowness by removing parallel plan inhibiting functions.But there are lots of plans being created for single queries and plan cache is getting cleared everyday or within last 24 hours.Dunno how to fix the memory pressure which is causing plan cache to clear.